# CSS color parameter escaping ID

Tags: css

I have this HTML page with CSS:
https://jsfiddle.net/0fk5uggt/

If i change this bit:

```
#artykuly_zawartosc a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

into this:

```
#artykuly_zawartosc a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: #183087;
}
```

the color paremeter overwrites the one I have in:

```
#artykuly_naglowek a:link, a:visited {}
```

I have been trying to figure this out for over an hour now, can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/0fk5uggt/1/

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `a:visited` part is the same in both. You have to prefix it separately.

```
#artykuly_zawartosc a:link, #artykuly_zawartosc a:visited {}
#artykuly_naglowek a:link, #artykuly_naglowek a:visited {}
```

Comment: Oh... my... god... how did I miss that? Thank's for your answer, that's excatly why it wasn't working :)

Answer (score 0):

You missed the parent selector for `a:visited` in both case. Also try to every new selector keep in new lines like following it will provide you better readability.

```
#artykuly_zawartosc a:link, 
#artykuly_zawartosc a:visited {}
#artykuly_naglowek a:link,
#artykuly_naglowek a:visited {}
```

Comment: Also I updated you fiddle version you may expecting this: https://jsfiddle.net/0fk5uggt/1/

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thanks for your help :)